# What kind of cloth is OK for cooking glutinous rice and how to handle it?

Tags: food-safety

I got myself some glutinous rice, but it's suggested that I use a cotton cloth in order to cook it. Thing is, I take food safety quite seriously and I wanted to know what kind of cloth specifically is OK to use and what isn't. For example, would a washed piece of a white t-shirt with no print be okay? If not, what to look for? I'm from Poland and I looked for "steam cooking" results on allegro.pl, but found nothing made for steam cooking. Also, how to properly clean it afterward in a food-safe way?

Comment: Use corn husks or bamboo leaves?

Answer (score 1):

I would look for [cheesecloth](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2019/05/thai-sticky-rice-khao-niao.html), it should be widely available.

If not, yes, a [white cotton shirt](https://www.thespruceeats.com/what-to-use-if-you-dont-have-cheesecloth-1388022) should be good enough, make certain it is not a blend of different fabrics; and I would wash it in boiling water before.